# What's the difference between {{}} and v-text in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

In vue.js we know there are two ways to bind data to a view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="app">

  <p>{{msg}}</p>
  <p v-text="msg"></p>

</div>

<script src="./lib/vue.js"></script>

<script>
  var vm = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
      msg: 'hello world',
    }
  })
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

You see the tag p:

```
<p>{{msg}}</p>
<p v-text="msg"></p>
```

Is there any difference between them?

Answer (score 7):

There are two differences between them:

1. If you use the `<p>{{msg}}</p>` to bind the data, you can add more content, such as:

   Hi, {{msg}}!
2. The `<p v-text="msg"></p>` can avoid the bind flashing, that mean when you load the view, there will not appear `{{msg}}` like the first way. If you want to use `<p>Hi, {{msg}}!</p>` way, you can add the `[v-cloak]` property:

```
<style>
    [v-cloak] {
      display: none;
    }
</style>

...

<p v-cloak>{{msg}}</p>
```